# Clearing and Defining an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have defined an array in a for loop.Something like

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $an_array = array();
}
```

Please let know if the array definition will also the clear the array after the first iteration.

Comment: What do you mean with "clear the loop"?

Comment: have you tried? did it "clear the loop"?

Comment: what's even the point of the loop there?  you're just executing the same statement over and over 5 times.

Comment: @thescientist it says "something like" so I guess it's just to illustrate the point but the OP could simply try and see for himself whether that does what s/he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh the array will be cleared each time.
You could create unique arrays each time with the follow if thats what you require.

```
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $an_array[$i] = array();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. 
$arr = array();
This makes the variable an empty array. 
If you want to add elements with a key defined, easiest way would be,
$arr[]='my data';
Use above code in the for loop and set the $arr = array(); above for loop. It's not required but recommended.

You can also add data like this:
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i){
 $arr[$i] = 'my data';
}

$arr will not be cleared after for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is being asked here or what your trying to accomplish but any variable that is defined in the loop will no longer be defined at the beginning of each iteration.

Try:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    var_dump($an_array);
    $an_array = array();
    array_push($an_array, $i);
    var_dump($an_array);
}
var_dump($an_array);
```

If your trying to populate this array by using a loop you will need to define the array prior to entering the loop like so:

```
 $an_array = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    array_push($an_array, $i);
}
var_dump($an_array);
```